# Shopify checkout redirect after payment with parameter

Tags: redirect, shopify

i want to redirect my customer to external set-password page after shopify checkout. To do that i need shopify to pass email parameter to the external url. Can someone help me?

Comment: I think you can add custom code into the Shopify backend advance scripts section, that runs once the user landed over the thank you page after completing the checkout.

Comment: on this page, you can easily get the data of order and customer in liquid and perform a redirect as per your custom requirements.